# How do I transfer from HTC SENSE to the computer?

Tags: file-transfer, htc-sense, data-transfer

I want to transfer contacts, photos and videos from my HTC SENSE to my computer. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try that with HTC Sync?

Comment: I assume you're on Windows?

Comment: As your phone is an HTC, I agree with Abhishek above about HTC Sync Manager, however you havent specified which HTC model you are using because it doesnt work with all HTC devices eg I have a HTC Desire S and cannot use HTC Sync Manager however see this link for HTC Sync http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [WebSharing Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.websharing&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5leHRhcHAud2Vic2hhcmluZyJd) available at Google Play/Android market. Once installed, you can navigate to an address set up by WebSharing via your computer and transfer any files you need.

EDIT: 
There are many applications to do this as pointed out by @richard-borcsik below. This is just one off the top of my head. If you establish a Google Account for your android device and then log into Gmail for that Google Account, the contacts that you have on the phone/device automatically show up in your Gmail Contacts list. At least, that has been my experience. So you may not really need a separate application to transfer/update contacts.

Comment: That only partially explains the question. It does not support contacts. And there're better apps for the task than the one you recommend.

Comment: @richard-borcsik Please do post your answer so I can check out those applications as well! It would be very handy to future Android users who have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is a Windows PC, I recommend using Snap Pea described as "Android's Best Friend". Theres a short video tutorial, as well as explanation on the main front page of its functions. (Having never used it myself i'm not sure if it transfer videos, but as its free you have nothing to lose)

http://www.snappea.com/

If you are using an Apple Mac and your phone is incompatible with HTC Sync Manager, then I recommend using Air Droid which is browser based.

http://www.airdroid.com/